# How to cause rollover on purpose in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, rollover

I'd like to cause a rollover like for example in the original Civ game where Ghandi was the most peaceful already and then the player increased the maximum pacifism value (255) by one and went to 0 (angry). I want to do arithmetic on a list or array and define a range (e.g. 0-255) and if a value after arithmetic is outside the bounds (minus values or anything over 255) it will just start from the beginning or go backward.
Example:

```py
list1 = [10,118,251,43,195] # add 150 to each value
output_list = [160,268,401,193,345] # but I want [160,13,146,193,90]
```

and similarly also if I subtract from each value, anything that goes below 0 would rollback from 255.

p.s. it doesn't have to be a list it could also be an array or some other way of doing it. At the moment I wrote a for loop checking each value but it's inelegant and only works if the over/under value is no more than 2X smaller/bigger than min/max value in the range.

```py
# My current code:
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] > 255:
        list1[i]=list1[i] - 255
    if list1[i] < 0:
        list1[i]=list1[i] + 255
```

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check out the mod operator `%`. For example, `258 % 256 == 2`.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: @quamrana you want me to upload my for loop or what do you mean?

Comment: Well, yes. Just like all the other python questions here.

Answer (score 2):

This "rollover" operation that you are referring to is usually called "modulo" or "remainder", since it corresponds to finding the remainder of a Euclidean division. It is also sometimes called "wraparound".

For instance, when we count hours in a day, we count modulo 12, so that 13:00 is equivalent to 01:00.

The modulo operation is denoted `%` in python. You can implement a custom `add` function that takes a threshold into account and applies the modulo operator:

```py
def add(x, y, threshold=256):
  return (x + y) % threshold

list1 = [10,118,251,43,195]
output_list = [add(x, 150) for x in list1]

print(output_list)
# [160, 12, 145, 193, 89]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly as I wanted!  I knew of modulo function but I guess I don't (didn't?) quite understand it completely ;) .